# How to upload just an image using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: image, file, upload, retrofit, retrofit2

Trying to upload an image and it keeps sending as just bytes, not an image file. This is a very simple call, I don't need to send any params other than the image itself. I don't know how to format logs so I won't post the error here unless requested to.

The service:

```
public interface FileUploadService {

@Multipart
@POST("upload_profile_picture")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadProfilePicture(@Part("profile_picture") RequestBody file);
}
```

The call being made (a file is generated earlier, had to remove this code because SO needs the post to be mainly words..dumb..):

```
    // Generate the service from interface
    FileUploadService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class, this);

    // Create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "formed file");

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadProfilePicture(requestFile);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "sending call");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "failure");
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Is the issue with the MediaType.parse method? I've tried "multipart/form-data", "image/jpeg", and the above as well and nothing has worked.

The server team has said they *are* receiving the call, just as bytes and no image file.

I keep getting a 400 because it's sending all bytes. How can I just send this? Do I need to send as a multipart or what? From what I've seen, you just need to tag the param in the method with @Body and do the above and it should all work. Can anybody tell me why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is a [known issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063) in Retrofit 2.</strike>

**Edit**: Support for OkHttp's `MultipartBody.Part` has been added in the final 2.0 release.

In order to get it working, you need to change your interface a little bit first:

```java
@Multipart
@POST("upload_profile_picture")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadProfilePicture(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Then you have to create the `Part` and make the call like this:

```java
MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "file",
            imageFile.getName(),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile));

Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadProfilePicture(file);
```